# Provide "regular" grammar for this language {${a^ib^j \mid i>0\ and \hspace{2.5mm}i\leq j \leq(2*i)}$}

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

I'm trying to understand the approach to constructing an grammar which accepts the language 
${a^ib^j \mid i>0\ and \hspace{2.5mm}i\leq j \leq(2*i)}$ }
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: unfortunately, it can't be done.

It can be proven mathematically that this language isn't regular. The easiest way is a fooling set argument: the set $\{a^{3^i} \mid i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is infinite, and for any two distinct strings $x$ and $y$ you take from this set, I can construct a suffix $z$ such that $xz$ is in your language and $yz$ is not.

Thus, it's utterly impossible to make a regular grammar for this language.

Note that this language *is* context-free; the following context-free grammar (CFG) recognizes it:

$$S \rightarrow aXb \mid aXbb \\
X \rightarrow aXb \mid aXbb \mid \varepsilon$$

(The distinction between $S$ and $X$ is just to ensure that $i > 0$; if you drop that requirement, you can do this in one line.)

EDIT: Thanks to Apass.Jack, here's a one-liner for you anyway!

$$S \rightarrow aSb \mid aSbb \mid ab \mid abb$$

Comment: Nice answer. Here is a oneliner. $S\rightarrow aSb \mid aSbb \mid ab\mid abb$

Comment: @Apass.Jack True, that works too!

Comment: Note that "problem dumps" such as this can often be answered by referring the asker to one of our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions).